# Can I call google.maps.event.addListenerOnce multiple times with the same argument?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to pan google map to a specific location after window has finished loading by Calling google.maps.event.addListenerOnce. However, I noticed that I can actually call google.maps.event.addListenerOnce multiple times and the same callback function got executed multiples time as well.

```js
    function addListener() {
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(window, 'load', function() {
            console.log('window loaded')
        });
    };

    addListener();
    addListener();
```

I expect the console log to be executed only once but it actually got executed multiple times.

Comment: Each time you add `addListenerOnce` it will add the listener.  It will execute once for it's associated event.  So the behavior you are seeing is expected.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for the clarification. However, I still think the method name is a bit misleading.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event#event.addListenerOnce) says "Like addListener, but the handler removes itself after handling the first event."

Comment: @geocodezip Also saw that in the API docs and "removes itself after handling the first event" reads like no matter how many handlers you assigned, only the first invocation should be executed. I guess this is either a bug in GMaps or wrong documentation.